# Receive Bearer Token from API with R

Tags: r, swagger, rcurl, httr

I'm searching for a solution to receive a Bearer token from an API using username and password.

Right now I'm reading the token through Chrome and extract my data, which is less then ideal of course.

I tried with httr and curl to optain through R and receive the Bearer token, but i think i am quite lost.

I think it should be quite simple, from the login information i gathered the mask from the login as 
`{"username":"name","password":"pw"}`, shouldn't this just work with the POST command and the right headers?

```
POST(url="api_login",config=add_headers(c("username: name"
                                        ,"password: pw")))
```

Doesn't work at all. I can provide the example for php which looks like this:

```
 <?php

        // Include Request and Response classes

        $url = 'url';

        $params = array(
                'username'  => 'sample_username',
                'password'  => 'sample_password'
            );

        // Create a new Request object
        $request = new Request($url, 'POST', $params);

        // Send the request
        $request->send();

        // Get the Response object
        $response = $request->getResponse();

        if($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {

            print_r($response->getBodyDecoded());
        }
        else {

            echo $response->getStatusCode() . PHP_EOL;
            echo $response->getReasonPhrase() . PHP_EOL;
            echo $response->getBody() . PHP_EOL;
        }
    ?>
```

As I'm not very familiar with php i would be very pleased for any help or a guide into the right direction. I searched hours
for API access through R but everything looks very specific to a special login.

I figured out this API uses a deprecated version of Swagger, if this is any useful information.

Comment: if you have access to an API, that API should give you token information you need by logging in to your account. can you share which service you are trying to gain API access to?

Comment: yes of course, documentation can be found on https://www.exoclick.com/developers/

Comment: see [link](https://api.exoclick.com/v1/manual/api_interface/README.html) API Interface manual

Comment: why are you trying to pull from your browser history rather than simply logging into your account with exoclick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats what I'm doing atm, login with the website and read the token out of my browser. I want to login from inside R, sorry if I wasn't clear.

I updated my code now to:

```
opts=curlOptions(verbose=TRUE, 
                 ssl.verifypeer = T)
postForm(url,
         "username:" = uname, "password:"=pswd,
         httpheader = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json', Accept = 'application/json'),
         .opts=opts,
         style='POST'
)
```

Which results in an error:  ***SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain.***

I tried a lot of different certificates with 'cainfo' inside the argument but can't make it work.

Comment: Finally i got the body right, content(POST(url,body = list(
  'username'=name,
  'password'=pw,
  'content-type' = 'application/json;',
  'transfer-encoding' = 'chunked'),encode = "json")) works.